# Python program and drawing a square

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, logo-lang

My program

```
import turtle
i = "input()"
while i == "input()":
    if i == "exit":
        input()
    if i == "fd":
        turtle.fd(1)
    if i == "bk": 
        turtle.bk(1)
    if i == "lt":
        turtle.lt(90)
    if i == "rt":
        turtle.rt(90)
    if i == "pu":
        turtle.pu()
    if i == "pd":
        turtle.pd()
```

Now the file that is my input is (fd,fd,fd,bk,bk,lt,rt etc)
it is suppose to draw a square but nothing shows up
what am i doing wrong

Comment: the iff are all in line just didn't put in right in this thing

Comment: The formatting would be fine if you were consistent with your use of tabs and spaces. Use one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 3):

In Python there is a function you can call, `input()`.  But you are not calling it.  You put quotes around it, so you are just referencing a string that contains the letters 'i', 'n', 'p', 'u', 't', '(', ')'.

Remove the quotes so you actually call the `input()` function.

EDIT: From your comment below, it looks like you are using Python 2.x; so you should use `raw_input()`.  `raw_input()` just returns whatever string the user typed; `input()` tries to evaluate it as a value.

```
x = input()  # if user types "2", x is set to the number 2
x = raw_input()  # if user types "2", x is set to the string "2"
```

EDIT: You need to make sure the pen is down, you probably want the turtle to go more than just 1 when going forward or back, and you need to make the screen appear.

I suggest you read a basic intro to turtle graphics in Python.

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/08/06/python-using-turtles-for-drawing/

Before the start of the while loop, try putting this:

```
screen = turtle.getscreen()
```

That should be enough to make the graphics screen pop up.

Good luck and have fun.

Comment: take all "" away or only a bit

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "as2.py", line 2, in <module>
    i = input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'fd' is not defined

Comment: Oh, you must be using Python 2.x instead of Python 3.x.  In that case, you should use `raw_input()`.  In Python 2.x, Python tries to evaluate whatever is typed into `input()`.

Comment: ok i got it to draw the square but the picture does not stay on the screen

Answer (score 3):

The line `while i == input():` (even after removing the quotes) is not assigning a value to `i`. It is comparing the result of `input()` to `i`, which is probably not what you intend.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, you want to take away the quotes around the function, not every single quote:

```
import turtle
while True:
    i = input()
    if i == "exit":
        break # stops the loop
    if i == "fd":
        turtle.fd(1)
    if i == "bk": 
        turtle.bk(1)
    if i == "lt":
        turtle.lt(90)
    if i == "rt":
        turtle.rt(90)
    if i == "pu":
        turtle.pu()
    if i == "pd":
        turtle.pd()
```

You got the `NameError` because if you took the quotes off of `"fd"`, you have a variable, `fd`, not a string. However, the variable `fd` has not been defined, therefore you get an error.

However, if you are using Python 2.x (not 3.x) you should use `raw_input()` (this returns a string):

```
import turtle
while True:
    i = raw_input()
    if i == "exit":
        break
    if i == "fd":
        turtle.fd(1)
    if i == "bk": 
        turtle.bk(1)
    if i == "lt":
        turtle.lt(90)
    if i == "rt":
        turtle.rt(90)
    if i == "pu":
        turtle.pu()
    if i == "pd":
        turtle.pd()
```